# Android: Logic on app launch and exit

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I want to be able to execute some logic when my Android application is launched and also when it exits. I understand that there is not really a concept of this as such in Android, as each activity has its own lifecycle.

Suppose I have activities A, B, C & D and A is the root activity.

**Application launch:**

- I could put the logic in `onCreate()` for A, but this is also called when the orientation is changed and (possibly, if memory is low) if the user hits the `Back` key from activity B, C or D.
- I could create a class that extends `Application` and put the logic in `onCreate()`. I tried this, but `onCreate()` was not called in the scenario where I press the `Home` key and then re-launch the application by clicking on the relevant icon in the main menu.

**Application exit:**

- I could put logic in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` for all activities, but again I need to be able to tell if this is not being called as a result of a transition to another activity in my application. Also, there is no guarantee that these functions will be called when there is low memory?.
- I could override onLeaveUserHint() in all activities - are there any drawbacks to doing this?.

**Edit (as requested by CommonsWare):**

**"Application launch"** - my interpretation of an application launch is when one of the activities in my activity is being displayed after none of them when displayed (e.g. the user clicked on my application icon in the main menu).

**"Application exit"** - my interpretation of an application "exit" is when none of my activities are being displayed as a result of the user intentionally leaving an activity  after one of them were displayed (e.g. by pressing the "Home" key or "Back" key).

(I hope this provides some clarification).

Comment: what do you mean by logic?

Comment: I just want to be able to call a function that executes some code (logic) when my application is launched or exited.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to explain, precisely, what you mean by "it exits". For example, you seem to think that "it exits" when the user presses HOME, and an app does not "exit" in that circumstance by any conventional definition of the verb "exit".

Comment: If you need to put your "Logic" in Activity and call it only once on start of app and on exit you can do something like:
App starts, you check in shared preferences is the app started for the first time - if yes -> Do your logic and save in shared preferences that you are finished. You can override onBackPressed() when user finishes with the app, do whatever you like and save whatever state of the app you need so that you can again call your "logic" when app starts again. Is  that what you had in mind ?

Comment: @vodich - yes, that sounds along the right track. However, the user may also exit the app by pressing the Home key (and there may be other scenarios that I haven't thought of).

Comment: As far as I researched there is no way of successfully intercepting home key for every API version, so you will be facing some problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to put your "Logic" in Activity and call it only once on start of app and on exit you can do something like:

App starts, you check in shared preferences is the app started for the first time - if yes -> Do your logic and save in shared preferences that you are finished.

You can override onBackPressed() when user finishes with the app, do whatever you like and save whatever state of the app you need so that you can again call your "logic" when app starts again.

Is that what you had in mind ?

Comment: This sounds almost there - maybe I can also intercept the Home key if I override onUserLeaveHint() (API level 3+)? or have you had problems with this method?.

Comment: Also, are there any other scenarios that allow the user to exit an application, for example clicking on a notification in the notification bar?. I am not sure that this is a "catch-all" solution.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to intercept HOME button successfully, at least I didn't see any post about it since you really shouldn't do it at the end because the expected behavior of app is something users are used to, also there are a lot of events that you might not be able to intercept (phone rings etc..)Maybe if you explain which kind of logic you plan to do we can help you further